# Disabling login prompt and/or VGA output

Tags: server, login, customization, vga

On a network appliance I am building, based on Ubuntu server I wish to perform the following customizations:

1. Disable the VGA output so if one connect a screen nothing will appear. This however shall not affect the ability to connect to the machine with ssh and control it
2. If that is not possible without re-compiling the kernel (action I wish to avoid as much as possible), I at least want that when machine boot completes, it will not show the login prompt, rather my own custom message.

How can I get either one of the above options

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To disable textual login on virtual terminal tty1...tty6, you can modify `/etc/init/tty1.conf` (and the other from `tty2.conf` to `tty6.conf`), substituting the line

```
exec /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty1
```

with something like the following:

```
exec /sbin/getty -8 -n -l /usr/local/bin/tty-replacement 38400 tty1
```

where `/usr/local/bin/tty-replacement` can be a simple shell script like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo ""
echo "This is a message"
echo ""
read ans
```

This should not prevent ssh login, that has nothing to do with ttys.

Remember to make the shell script executable with

```
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/tty-replacement
```

Comment: I need to do similar thing on Ubuntu 16.04 but your resolution does not work. Is that now handled by systemd? Do you have any idea how to fix this?